# How to build array of 'bad' values

Tags: php, arrays

I am processing a form and in turn, receiving a response code based on the information submitted. I have a list of approximately 40 response codes (and their meaning) in my hands and am trying to build an 'if' statement that checks against a predefined array and returns a specific value.

Just not sure how to do this

### First pass conceptually:

```
$bads = array (1,2,3,4,5,6)


if ($output['responsecode'] == (any value in $bads) {
echo "you suck";
}
```

### EDIT - Still receiving errors

I am using the following code:

```
$bad_resp1 = array("D","M","A","B","W","Z","P","L","N","C","U","G","I","R","E","S","0","O","B");
$bad_resp2 = array("N","P","S","U");
$bad_resp3 = array("200","201","202","203","204","220","221","222","223","224","225","250","261","262","263","264","300","400","410","411","420","421","430","440","441","460","461");
```

then calling the 'if' statement:

```
if (in_array($output['response1'], $bad_resp1) || in_array($output['response2'], $bad_resp2) || in_array($output['response3'], $bad_resp3)) {
            Header("Location: fail.php");
        }
```

I get the following error(s):

> Warning: in_array() expects parameter
>   2 to be array, null given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\site\xyz.php on line
>   362
>
> Warning: in_array() expects parameter
>   2 to be array, null given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\site\xyz.php on line
>   362
>
> Warning: in_array() expects parameter
>   2 to be array, null given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\site\xyz.php on line
>   362

Comment: you're missing a right paren there :P

Comment: Does your reporting manager suck or you suck. Just out of topic. just kidding

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Can you post your actual code?

Comment: @Anthony - that is my actual code. I am submitting a request via API, in return responses are generated and sent back to me in string which I am parsing out. I am certain the responses are being sent back in such response1 would equal a single letter of the alphabet and so on.

Comment: `var_dump` the arrays before the `if` statement to ensure they are being assigned. Also, make sure any files you are trying to include are actually being included.

Comment: @Tim - the issue was resolved, moved the variable arrays further down within the class and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[in_array](http://php.net/in_array)

```
if(in_array($output['responsecode'], $bads))
{

}
```

Also, if your codes are sequential, you can use [range](http://php.net/range) to generate the array.

```
$bad = range(1, 10);
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `in_array()`

```
if (in_array($output['responsecode'], $bads)) { echo "you suck"; }
```

Comment: running this code, I receive the following error: Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, you can do:

```
if (in_array($output['responsecode'], $bads))
    ....
```

However, this is more efficient because it does not require a traversal of the $bads array:

```
$bads = array (1 => null, 2 => null, 3 => null, 4 => null,5 => null, 6 => null);


if (array_key_exists($output['responsecode'], $bads))
    ....
```

Comment: the values returned are alpha characters (A,B,C)

Comment: It doesn't matter. Array keys can be strings.

Comment: I am receiving the following error: Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in...

Answer (score 0):

How about you have a `$errors` array and only add to it if there's an error. If the `$errors` array is not empty, `echo "All aboard the fail train!"`

Comment: Then you still need something to check if the response is good or bad.